# qt designer: how to switch off dpi scaling

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm having issues with qt designer. Since I changed my graphics card I get everything scaled up in qt designer, and I can't see any way to change that. Is there a way to switch off dpi scaling in qt designer?

[image]

I have some information [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html), but it doesn't seem to work and it's not affecting qt designer in any way it seems. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, does the problem persist when you do a preview (Ctrl+R)? If it does, try changing the scale settings for windows (Settings->Display->Scale and Layout). Don't know if this is exactly what you need, but it could help. You could also try setting the preview for the Qt Designer.